# Iterate(foreach) through member variable in C# in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, for-loop

is it possible to access directly the variable i in the foreach header without using temp?

```
class A
{
    public int i{get; set;}
}
...
A[] many_As=new A[1000]

foreach (var element in many_As)
{
    int temp=element.i;
    ...
}
...
```

->

```
foreach (int element in many_As.i)
{
   //doing something with element
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use use [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0):

```
...

using System.Linq;

...


foreach(var element in many_As.Select(x = >x.i)) 
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 7 you can do the following:

```cs
foreach (var (value, index) in collection.Select((val, idx)=>(val, idx))) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{index + 1}th item is: {value}");
}
```

Here we are making use of [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) and [tuple deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).